# Unable to understand python program

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to figure out how this code actually executes but im so confused. Can anyone explain it?

Code:

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k > 0):
    result = k + tri_recursion(k -1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result
tri_recursion(6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program prints six sums. The first sum printed is the sum of the numbers integers 0 to 6, the second is the sum of the integers between 0 to 5, and so on, all the way down to the sum of 0 and 1 (which equals 1.) The program does this by implementing recursive calls.

I recommend you spend 10 minutes tracing the program line by line on a blank sheet of paper. Imagine instead of using 6 as the input, try to follow the program using 2 as the input.

So instead of

```
tri_recursion(6)
```

try

```
tri_recursion(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to learn about the call stack: [https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs8/topics.beta/theStack/02/](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Epconrad/cs8/topics.beta/theStack/02/)

If you work through to lesson 6, you'll also find recursion explained there.